# Sorting a vector of mixed values (i.e. sort string on number then character)

Tags: r

I'm trying to sort the following vector of characters based on 1) numbers and 2) characters:

```
"BLH-07", "BLH-08", "AFH-08", "AFH-09"
```

I've tried to use mixedsort, however it doesn't work at present.

```
library(gtools)
vector = c("BLH-07", "BLH-08", "AFH-08", "AFH-09")
sort = mixedsort(vector, decreasing = TRUE)
```

My result:

```
"BLH-07", "BLH-08", "AFH-08", "AFH-09"
```

Desired result:

```
"BLH-07", "AFH-08", "BLH-08", "AFH-09"
```

-> Thus, sorting first on the numbers in the string, and next alphabetically on BLH, AFH...

Comment: Try to split and then do the order `vector[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", vector)), gsub("\\d+", "", vector), decreasing = TRUE)]`

Comment: thanks @akrun! That works